# Looking for a sefer abbreviated מק"ק

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books

I'm looking for a sefer which is abbreviated as מק"ק. I've seen it quoted primarily refering to halachos of Krias Hatorah. Any ideas what the sefer may be called or where I can find it?

Comment: If you share the source it will be easier to ascertain the right roshei teivos

Answer (score 4):

The sefer I was looking for was [מקראי קודש](https://hebrewbooks.org/8939) by [R' Zvi Hersh Grodzinsky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zvi_Hirsch_Grodzinsky). a three volume work on Hilchos Krias Hatorah.